# Cannot play videos

Tags: video, omxplayer

I have the latest version of Raspbian on the Pi 3.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.24-v7+ #993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have never been able to play a video (mp4, avi). I am using omxplayer. Even the test video does not work.

```
omxplayer /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264
Video codec omx-h264 width 1920 height 1080 profile 77 fps 25.000000
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
V:PortSettingsChanged: 1920x1080@25.00 interlace:0 deinterlace:0 anaglyph:0 par:1.00 display:0 layer:0 alpha:255 aspectMode:0
```

H264 codec is enabled:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd codec_enabled H264
H264=enabled
```

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: The simplest possible test I can think of with omxplayer is to navigate your terminal to the directory containing the file you want to play (to avoid any possible problems from unqualified paths), then using *omxplayer myfile.mp4*. Could you try that and report back?

Comment: My Raspberry is still telling me to have a nice day.                                                   pi@raspberrypi:/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video $ omxplayer test.h264 
Video codec omx-h264 width 1920 height 1080 profile 77 fps 25.000000
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
V:PortSettingsChanged: 1920x1080@25.00 interlace:0 deinterlace:0 anaglyph:0 par:1.00 display:0 layer:0 alpha:255 aspectMode:0
have a nice day ;)

Comment: Can you define "does not work"?

Comment: By "does not work", I mean that a black screen is shown when the video should be playing. There is no sound. The video counter counts up the time as though the video is playing.

Comment: Try changing the GPU memory split in the /boot/config.txt file. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/memory.md

Comment: does it play on VNC correctly ?

Comment: @Guy.D The video does play in VLC. However not very well. It is dropping a lot of frames.

Comment: @Guy.D The video does play in VLC but it's dropping a lot of frames. Log excerpt shows (Note I have removed parts of log):- X Error: BadGC (invalid GC parameter) 13
  Major opcode: 60 (X_FreeGC)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[016fe648] pulse audio output error: stream connection failure: Timeout
[6a0fa228] core decoder error: failed to create audio output
[h264 @ 0x648e09a0] mmco: unref short failure
[6487f9a0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)

Comment: @Jonathan I had similar problems while trying to play video stream from IPcamera (mostly dropping frames, stalls and so ). I lowered the window size (zoom 1:2 ) which made it easier for the GPU  to play. give it a try. Besides that, I did encounter it while playing video clips- and surely the higher framerate you go the more stalls you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try Reinstalling: 
sudo apt-get purge omxplayer; sudo apt-get install omxplayer